# Excel VLOOKUP with multiple columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to validate data from two different sources to find differences in order to evaluate them. In order to make sure the VLOOKUP works, I need to make sure that the $ amount and Primary Key are the fields that have to match across a given row. The two tables hold the same format information, I just need to make sure they match!

I want to match **Amount** and **NameID** across the two tables and then **return** the **Transaction Type** back into a new column in **Table 1**. If the transaction type does not match, I know that I need to check that transaction to make sure things were input properly.

**TABLE 1**

Account # | Transaction Type | **Amount** | **NameID (PK)** | Date

**TABLE 2**

Account # | **Transaction Type** | Amount | NameID (PK) | Date
I guess I am just not sure if this is possible with VLOOKUP or if INDEX MATCH is better (either way I do not know how to do it).

Comment: I don't understand why IFERROR is being used. I won't ever divide by 0. I don't even understand why that is being done in the question you linked.

Comment: @jeeped -- The question you referenced probably does answer this question. However, the answer was "Nothing to it. Multiple criteria columns can be added as TRUE/FALSE statements multiplied against the denominator that produces the #DIV/0! errors." I'm pretty experienced with Excel, and I would have to play with that formula to understand what that meant, so I'm not sure it qualifies as an answer for a typical Excel user. On the other hand, I have to assume that the multiple-criteria problem has been answered clearly somewhere else. The simplest way seems to be using helper columns.

Comment: I think the first answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25499167/5749389) will work as a template for you. Ignore the subsequent discussion, just use the first formula and the OP example. If your tables are in different worksheets, you'll have to include sheet names as needed.